# How to export results of cross validation in python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn to train my model. But i want to export results to excel file for my own calculation.
Here is my code

```py
data = pd.read_excel("TN QSAR.xlsx")
X = data.drop(['label','My ID','Smiles','pEC50'], axis=1)
y = data['pEC50']
model = linear_model.LinearRegression() 
cv = KFold(n_splits=3)
i = 1
for train,test in cv.split(X):
    model.fit(X[train], y[train])
    y_pred = model.predict(X)
    y_pred_test = model.predict(X[test])
    y_pred_train = model.predict(X[train])
    y_pred_df = pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns = ['y_pred'], index = X.index.copy())
    y_pred_train_df = pd.DataFrame(y_pred_train, columns = ['y_pred_train'], index = X[train].index.copy())
    y_pred_test_df = pd.DataFrame(y_pred_test, columns = ['y_pred_test'], index = X[test].index.copy())
    dftraintest = pd.concat([y,y_pred_df,y_pred_train_df,y_pred_test_df],axis=1)
    i = i+1
    dftraintest.to_excel('dftraintest',i,'.xlsx')
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you share your complete traceback output of the error?

Comment: This ia all my output of the error:

Comment: Be careful when getting train/test data from X and y. They are Pandas dataframes so you need to use "iloc" for that instead of direct data selection.

Comment: Your latest edits do not seem to improve this question - if anything, they remove useful details (even though [images of data are of highly dubious value.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)) Rolling back your edits will only create more noise, but if you hope to get this question reopened, you really should try to make it more useful, not less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in the way you pass the data.
change the `X[train]` to `X.loc[train, :]`, `y[train]` to `y.loc[train]` etc.

besides that, im not sure if the way you pass the url parameter to `to_excel(url)` is right. if that gives also an error, try:

1. `'dftraintest' + str(i) +'.xlsx'` or
2. `'dftraintest {}{}'.format(i, '.xlsx')`